# If XmlException.SourceUri is read-only, what good is it?

Tags: c#, get-method, xmlexception

I have a couple places in my code where it throwing a new System.Xml.XmlException seems appropriate. I could just do

```
throw new XmlException("Your XML sucks go fix it then try again.");
```

But I think it's better to take advantage whenever possible of members particular to the exception class (otherwise ya might as well throw a plain ol' `Exception` every time). SourceUri and LineNumber would be helpful, but they *only* have `get` methods, there's no way I can assign a value to them! There's only 3 constructor overloads and none of them have parameters for those members either; I can only initialize `Message`, nothing else.

There has got to be *some* way to populate those data members with values, otherwise why does XmlException bother with them?

I suppose I could make a new class that inherits XmlException and write a new constructor that initializes SourceUri etc. but still, there must be a way to just use XmlException. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a constructor that takes a `sourceUri` parameter :

```
internal XmlException(string res, string[] args, string sourceUri)
```

But since it is internal, it can only be called inside the System.Xml assembly. Anyway, I don't think you should throw an `XmlException` yourself. This exception is typically thrown by the XML-related BCL classes. You should rather create your own exception and throw it instead.

Comment: OK, an internal constructor makes sense in that case. Of course I could inherit from XmlException, then I'd have access to the `protected` members.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* [a constructor with the line number and line position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftkk2e9.aspx). I can't see anything that takes SourceUri though...

I believe you *can* populate it using the serialization streaming context - but that would be pretty fragile.

I think it's best to regard it as something which is effectively only provided by system-thrown XmlExceptions. I don't think that makes it useless - just less flexible than it might be. (I suspect the vast majority of XmlExceptions that are thrown in the world *are* thrown by the system rather than by user code.)

Comment: True, and if the streaming context did work to change the value of SourceUri, that's probably more of a security bug than a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look using Reflector, and it would seem that only two constructors set the SourceUri. Those are the deserialization one, and a single internal constructor that sets everything, but all the public ones call that with the SourceUri set to null. Obviously none of those can be easily accessed. I would conclude that there is no good way to set the SourceUri property.